# Horizontal scrolling page of images with no border/padding and vertically centered on the page! Possible?

Tags: css

I've looked at a number of examples of horizontal scrolling and centering content vertically, but none in combination - and this seems to have created a real challenge!  (and a sore head!)

Here's where I am at - the page scrolls fine, but the content isn't vertically centered and the images have spacing around them (caused by white-space: nowrap; ??)

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background:#272727;
    }

    .wrapper {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .container {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .content {
        float:left;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;    
    }

    img {
        display:inline;
        border:none;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML + make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo of what you have so far?

Comment: http://www.sei-london.com/slides/formans2012.html

Comment: I'll also have a fiddle of jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var screenHeight = $(document).height();
var contentHeight = 733;
var difference = (screenHeight - contentHeight)/2;
alert(difference);
$('.content').css({'margin-top': difference});
});

</script>
```

Comment: How about trying jquery? Just paste my edited version of the answer above into your page right before the closing </body> tag. And remove the inline styles you have on your <div class="content" style=""...
and <div class="container" style=""...